# Should the main functions of a program be in a separate object?

Tags: programming-practices

For a class project in Introduction to Object Orientated Programming, we are creating a simple game.

This game has two main menus. I was just wondering what the best practice for organizing these are. Should I have these functions in a separate object or should I keep these as separate methods?

To me it makes more sense to create separate methods for each and call it in the main like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // call sub module and create objects
}
```

Any help on this? I figure it will be coming up a lot throughout programming so I want to know the best practices for handling this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest storing your menu structure in some hierarchical data structure:

```
//C# sample
//You can replace the object initializers with constructors in the class,
//In C# 6.0, you can also create an Add extension method taking three parameters, for use with the collection initializer
//    https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#extension-add-methods-in-collection-initializers

class MenuEntry {
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public Action Action {get;set;}
    public List<MenuEntry> Subentries {get;set;}
}

var entries = new List<MenuEntry> {
    new MenuEntry() {Title = "TopLevel1", Subentries = new List<MenuEntry>() {
        new MenuEntry() {Title = "SecondLevel1", Action = () => SecondLevel1()},
        new MenuEntry() {Title = "SecondLevel2", Action = () => SecondLevel2()}
    },
    new MenuEntry() {Title = "TopLevel2", Subentries = new List<MenuEntry>() {
        new MenuEntry() {Title = "SecondLevel3", Action = () => SecondLevel3()},
        new MenuEntry() {Title = "SecondLevel4", Action = () => SecondLevel4()}
    }
}
```

Then all you need is a single recursive function to render each `MenuEntry` to the corresponding UI element, and connect the `Action` to that element.

All else being equal, it is simplest to group the called methods (`SecondLevel1`, `SecondLevel2`) together, either in the same class as the `main` method, or in a separate static class for all these methods. However, it may be more appropriate to keep some or all individual methods together with the appropriate parts of the application: e.g. a `StartNewGame` method might belong with the `Game` class.